# init.d/mysql - Default configuration is blocking one of my instances on startup

Tags: mysql, linux, redhat

I am having a bit of an issue that popped up over the past weekend.

One of my servers was rebooted and when the server came it started a default instance of mysql that is configured upon installation. It uses port 3306 as a default and blocks one of my instances from coming up.

**How can I remove this default instance from booting and instead boot my instances in /etc/my.cnf ?**

I think what is happening is it is going to `/var/lib/mysql` and starting an instance based off some default configuration as there is not a `my.cnf` file located here, but I find this code in init.d:

```
#Set some defaults 
mysqld_pid_file_path= 
if test -z "$basedir" 
then 
  basedir=/usr 
  bindir=/usr/bin 
if test -z "$datadir" 
then 
  datadir=/var/lib/mysql 
fi
```

But I don't see any `my.cnf` file at that location that it could be pulling configuration options from.

My data directories change per instance and they are all specified in `/etc/my.cnf`

I appreciate any effort spent helping with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ my_print_defaults --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf mysqld
```

This will show you what it thinks datadir is set to, according to your config file.

I've seen config files get confused as people edit them, or even automated tools may edit the config file and append new config entries. Keep in mind if the config file has more than one line defining `datadir`, the *last* such line in the file takes precedence.

---

If you have an instance of mysqld starting up automatically at boot time, I'd use `chkconfig` to find out when that's happening. For example, here's a command run on my VM:

```
$ chkconfig
...
mysql           0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
...
```

The numbers 0 through 6 are runlevels, and "on" means that when the given runlevel starts, the `/etc/init.d/mysql` service script is run by `init`.

You can also use `chkconfig` to modify which runlevels a given service starts under, and even to disable the service at all runlevels, so that it won't start automatically ever.

```
$ chkconfig --level 2345 mysql off
```

Refer to `man chkconfig` for more uses.

Comment: Mysqld is not one of my instances stated in my `/etc/my.cnf`, but it is the default instance that is starting up so I feel like it must be starting up from somewhere else. Any suggestions or anything I can provide to better clarify?

Comment: Hm, this could work, I could disable the `init.d/mysql` altogether and use a different startup script using `mysqld_multi` to start all of my instances. I'll keep that in mind so I have a game plan in my back pocket in the event that I can't configure `init.d/mysql` properly. Thanks for your assistance.